# View and choose files to delete from list

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bunch of graphs saved as png files. Most of them are not very useful, but some are very useful.

I want to write a script that will display them each one at a time and wait for me to hit y or n. If I hit n, delete it. If not, move on to the next one.

I'm running into two problems.

First, feh opens a new window so I have to alt-tab back into my shell in order to press y or n. Is it possible to have bash listen for any key presses including ones in different windows?

Second, I was trying to use read to listen for a character, but it says that -n is not a valid option. That same line works fine in the terminal though.

Any idea how to do this?
Appreciate the help.

```
#! /bin/sh                                                                                                                                                               

FILES=./*.png
echo $FILES
for FILE in $FILES
do
    echo $FILE
    feh "$FILE" &
    CHOICE="none"
    read -p "d to delete, any other key to keep: " CHOICE -n 1 -s
    killall feh
    if [$CHOICE -eq "d"]
    then
        rm $FILE
    fi
done
```

Comment: I don't wish to take the fun out of your programming project but if you simply want this task _done_ the `qiv` image viewer provides a very handy `d` key binding that moves images to a `.qiv-trash/` directory. Run `qiv -fmt *` and get rid of your useless images in a hurry.

Comment: Just found out that feh has the same thing, but it is ctrl-delete. So I guess the problem is solved although I am still interested in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might only be tangential to your question, but your script is set to use `/bin/sh` (the POSIX shell) for execution but you are probably using `/bin/bash` as your *interactive* terminal shell. `read` handles differently depending upon which shell you're using:

Here's the output of your one `read` command three different shells; the `dash` shell is used for `/bin/sh` on my system, but to make sure it handles the same when called as `sh` and as `dash`, I've run it twice, once with each name:

```
$ bash
$ read -p "d to delete, any other key to keep: " CHOICE -n 1 -s
d to delete, any other key to keep: d
bash: read: `-n': not a valid identifier
$ exit
$ dash
$ read -p "d to delete, any other key to keep: " CHOICE -n 1 -s
d to delete, any other key to keep: d
read: 1: -n: bad variable name
$ 
$ pdksh
$ read -p "d to delete, any other key to keep: " CHOICE -n 1 -s
pdksh: read: -p: no coprocess
$ $ sh
$ read -p "d to delete, any other key to keep: " CHOICE -n 1 -s
d to delete, any other key to keep: d
read: 1: -n: bad variable name
$ 
$
```